# is there a function for finding the node with least numbe of vertices in a BVL tree?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, avl-tree

i have this class:

```
public class BVLNode {
    int data;
    BVLNode left, right;

    public BVLNode(int d, BVLNode l, BVLNode r) {
        data = d;
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
```

i have to add a function called :

```
 public BVLNode MinBVL(int h)
```

which get's a height of the given tree and has to return the root of the subtree with the minimum number of vertices and then set the data to equal to the number of the vertices of the root found.

Comment: *"the root of the subtree with the minimum number of vertices"*: surely that subtree would be a **leaf**, having just itself as vertex. I must be missing something, or did you mean the child (either left or right) with the minimum number of vertices in the subtree it roots?

Comment: exactly what i meant, i have to find the root of that subtree and return it and update the data to be the numbe of vertices,depends on the given height (int h)